# Where do you put non-controller, non-model code in a ASP.Net MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Where do you put non-controller, non-model code, like util classes, extension methods and so on in a ASP.Net MVC project? Maybe there's not a specific place to put it, you just put it anywhere, if so, any recommendation? Any best practices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it's a single class i put them in a "Library" folder on the project root. If it's a bit bigger I use a specific folder and if it's something more complex i create a new project in the same solution.

Comment: What would the benefits be with adding a new project instead of folder in the current project?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Kigg Sample MVC web project (You can get it from the official ASP.net), they put extension utility classes with a subfolder under root.

Answer (score 1):

Good references for ASP.NET MVC Best Practice

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/03/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-2.aspx

Comment: They are interesting posts, but I can't really find the answer to my question there.

Answer (score 1):

`App_Code` [is intended for such purpose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx#Anchor_1) if I'm not mistaken.

Anything stored here (including in subfolders) will be accessible throughout the application.

In VS2015 Community (probably others as well but I've not checked) it's even in the context menu under `Add -> Add ASP.NET Folder -> App_Code` along with a few others.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for. I have a class for encrypting querystrings and didn't have anywhere to put it in my Razor Pages Solution.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to put them where they are used most. So if it is the controller that uses them put it with the controller, and so on.